# checking if first char is equal to last char

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to java and I was wondering on how to return my code to false if the 1st and last letter aren't the same

he whole instruction was to define and test a method called checkString that will take in the word as a parameter and checks whether the String begins and ends with the same letter. If both letters are the same the method returns true otherwise false (returns a boolean). The program treats lower and uppercase letters as equivalent

here's what I have:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Excercise5 {
        public static void main(String[] arg) {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Type a string: ");
            String word = keyboard.nextLine(); 
            System.out.printf ("%s begins and ends with the same letter.", checkString(word));
        }
        public static boolean checkString (String word) {   
            int stringLength = word.length();
            String letter1 = (word.substring (0,1)).toUpperCase();
            String lastletter = (word.substring ((stringLength-1),(stringLength))).toUpperCase();

            if (letter1.equals(lastletter)){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could use `String.charAt()` instead of `String.substring()` to get your characters, and use `==` to compare them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your code; instead of:

```
if (letter1.equals(lastletter)) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Just do:

```
return letter1.equals(lastletter);
```

However your `checkString() {...}` code should be:

```
public static boolean checkString (String word) {
  int len = word.length();
  word = word.toUpperCase(); //since you are testing them as upper case
  char firstLetter = word.charAt(0);
  char lastLetter = word.charAt(len - 1);
  return firstLetter == lastLetter;
}
```

Also instead of:

```
System.out.printf (word + " begins and ends with the same letter.", checkString(word));
```

Use `print()`:

```
System.out.print(word + " begins and ends with the same letter: " + checkString(word));
```

**Edit:**

If you want to use `printf()` try something like:

```
System.out.printf("%s begins and ends with the same letter. %s", word , checkString(word));
```

`%s` is like a place holder for `word` and the value returned by `checkString(word)`.

Comment: but how do I make the program not print "'word' begins and ends with the same letter."? cause even if i use "return letter1.equals(lastletter);" it still prints it

Comment: @hannahGomez I have edited the answer according to what I understood from the problem, see if this solves it.

Comment: also i'm only allowed to use printf statement so if use `System.out.printf (word + " begins and ends with the same letter.", checkString(word));` would that work?

Comment: @hannahGomez I have edited the answer to use `printf()`

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following:

```
public boolean firstAndLast(String word)
{
    return Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0)) == Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(word.length()-1));
}
```

This checks the positions of 0 and length - 1 to see if they're equal to each other. If they are, it returns true, if not, false.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to one-line it:

```
return (word.substring (0,1)).toUpperCase().equals(word.substring(word.length()-1).toUpperCase());
```

Before the `.equals(...)` it fetches the first character, converts it to one case, doesn't matter which one as long as you are using the same case later on.

`word.substring(string.length()-1).toUpperCase();`

Fetches the last key and converts it to upper case.

This is how I would write it most likely

```
private boolean isFirstAndLastEqual (String word) {
    char first = Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0));
    char last  = Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(word.length()-1));

    return first == last;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't word.charAt(word.length()) return an out of bounds exception? The length is how long the word is. If your word is `word`, the length is 4, but the last character is position 3, because it starts at 0.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need such a complicated code.

Here is a very simple written method that does the work perfectly.

---

### Code

```
public static boolean checkString (String word) {
    return word.toLowerCase().charAt(0) == word.toLowerCase().charAt(word.length()-1);
}
```

---

### Explaination

It compares the first and the last character of the String input put to lowercase so that it matches the lower and uppercases.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of printf is wrong as you are not printing out the true/false value.  Either add a boolean specifier to your output string or use println instead.

```
    System.out.printf (word + " begins and ends with the same letter - %b\n", checkString(word));

    System.out.println (word + " begins and ends with the same letter " +  checkString(word));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following

```
public static boolean checkString(final String word) {
        final String checkedString = word.toLowerCase();
        final char[] chararray = checkedString.toCharArray();
        if (chararray.length > 1) {
            return chararray[0] == chararray[chararray.length-1];
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

This will convert the String to lower case. (You could also achieve this with `word.toUpperCase();`) After that the String is converted to a char Array and then checks the first and the last "char". if the given String is of length "0" then `true` will be returned. Depending on how you want to decide for emtpy Strings you could also change this to `false`

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you're looking for.

This gets the first letter (character at index 0): `firstletter = (word.charAt(0)).toUpperCase();`

This gets the last letter: `firstletter = (word.charAt(0)).toUpperCase();`The last character is at index `word.length-1`. For example, if your word is "apple", it has a length of 5, but the last character is at index 4 (remember, 0-4 not 1-5; letter1 is misleading, it's actually letter0).

As mentioned by Savior Self, using `charAt` is more efficient. Also, being that you'd use `char`'s rather than `String`'s and `==` to compare them.

Also, you would assign the return value to a variable when you call `checkString`. For instance, `boolean checkStr = checkString(word);` and then use `checkStr` in your print statement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
        public class Excercise5 {
            public static void main(String[] arg) {
                Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("Type a string: ");
                String word = keyboard.nextLine(); 
                boolean checkStr = checkString(word);
                System.out.println(word + " begins and ends with the same letter: " + checkStr;
            }
            public static boolean checkString (String word) {
                char firstletter = (word.charAt(0)).toUpperCase();
                char lastletter = (word.charAt(word.length-1)).toUpperCase();
                return (firstletter == lastletter);
            }
        }
```

Also, since I don't have enough points to comment, a better one-liner would be:

`return (word.charAt(0)).toUpperCase() == (word.charAt(word.length-1)).toUpperCase());`